# How can I make Microsoft GRAPH token acquisition faster?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am currently implementing an SSO-OBO flow for my addin. In this flow, I basically request for a bootstrap token from the Azure Identity platform using the Office.Auth.getAccessToken() API. And then exchange that for a Microsoft GRAPH token using  the auth-code flow. And it works correctly.

This entire process of getting the Bootstrap token, and exchanging it for a Microsoft GRAPH token takes around 2.52 seconds. (Average time over 10 trials.)

I have 2 questions related to this :

1. Is 2.52 seconds normal for this type of transaction?
2. If it is not normal, are there any documents or techniques that can help me increase the speed of this 'exchange'?

Please note that I used a free account AWS-Lambda/API Gateway for the tests I executed. I am not so sure if that affects latency. Also the test was done using a 50mbps connection.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have similar numbers (a bit faster though, ~800ms. Probably it's related to the azure datacenter location vs your app location). The bandwidth does not matter, as the amount of data transferred is tiny, but ping does (I'd at least make sure that your AWS app and Azure datacenter you are making request to, are located in the same country / part of the world)
2. You can cache the token (in the local storage, for example) and use the cached copy until it expires. The expiration time is written in the token itself ("exp" field, you can look at the contents of the token using the https://jwt.io for example). Or you could use some library that would do caching for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. First, on caching the token, i was thinking about doing this too. Thanks for giving me the jwt.io link, this is very helpful. As for the ~800ms, this is awesome. Well within what I wanted. But how do I determine the azure datacenter location? Thanks again.

Comment: As far as I know, that's where your tenant is registered (azure ad => properties). Although this info must be replicated worldwide probably. I just host the site on azure as well, so can't be sure here. https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. I will try your suggestions for this item and update this ticket (accept as answer) once I get my tests in place. Thanks again.